# Query mongoose returns no results with $regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Trying to build a mongoose query with regex but for some reason it always returns zero results.

I have a model called Place with value wind_direction. wind_direction is a string and looks something like this:

```
place.wind_direction = "SW, WSW, W, WNW, NW, NE, ENE, E";
```

I get values through a form, in this case "W, WNW, NW" and try to build a regex like this:

```
var string = JSON.stringify(req.body.wind_direction)
string = string.replace(/[\[\]"]+/g,'').split(",")
var reg = ""
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
   reg += "\b" + string[i] + "\b|";
}
reg = "/" + reg.substring(0, reg.length - 1) + "/";
query.wind_direction = { "$regex": reg, "$options": "i" }
```

When i console.log my query it looks like this:

```
{ wind_direction: { '$regex': '/\bW\b|\bWNW\b|\bNW\b/', '$options': 'i' } }
```

Then when I run a simple query with Place.find(query, function(req,res... it returns no results. But when I test my regex in an online regex tester it works.

Comment: Try just `query.wind_direction = { "$regex": new RegExp("\\b(?:" + req.body.wind_direction.join("|") + ")\\b"), "$options": "i" }` or `query.wind_direction = { "$regex": "\\b(?:" + req.body.wind_direction.join("|") + ")\\b", "$options": "i" }`

Comment: Thanks! First comment works for me. Didn't know about the existence of "?:" which makes life so much easier!

Comment: Just to make sure, `query.wind_direction = { "$regex": new RegExp("\\b(?:" + req.body.wind_direction.join("|") + ")\\b"), "$options": "i" }` works, right? Or the second one?

Comment: First one works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your `req.body.wind_direction` is already an array that you may use to build the alternation pattern, there is no need to `JSON.stringify` this array. To build an alternation, you may use `arr.join("|")`.

In order to avoid repeating `\b`, you may group all the alternatives, and a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) suits here best: `\b(?:term1|term2|termN)\b`.

You may use

```
query.wind_direction = { "$regex": new RegExp("\\b(?:" + req.body.wind_direction.join("|") + ")\\b"), "$options": "i" }
```